# NoSuchFieldException for fields added using Javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I am trying to add a field to a class. I have tried below approaches for adding the field using Javassist. I am trying to get the field using reflection, but it throws `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException`.

**Approach 1**

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass clazz = classPool.get("com.mypack.MyClass");
CtField field = new CtField(CtClass.longType, "myNewField", clazz);
field.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
clazz.addField(field, javassist.CtField.Initializer.constant(10L));
```

**Approach 2**

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass clazz = classPool.get("com.mypack.MyClass");
CtField field = CtField.make("public long myNewField = 10;", clazz);
clazz.addField(field);
```

**Approach 3**

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass clazz = classPool.get("com.mypack.MyClass");
ClassFile cf = clazz.getClassFile();
FieldInfo f = new FieldInfo(cf.getConstPool(), "myNewField", "I");
f.setAccessFlags(AccessFlag.PUBLIC);
cf.addField(f);
```

**Retrieving using reflection**

```
Field myField = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myNewField");
System.out.println("----- "+ serField.get(null));
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or if I am missing anything.

Thank you.

Comment: You specifically want to use Java's `getDeclaredField` and not `CtClass.getDeclaredField`? Not sure you can do that--you might want to look over https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#load.

Comment: Not really. All I am trying to check is whether the field got added with the value provided. I couldn't find the field using a decompiler (jd-gui or in IntelliJ). So thought of doing it programmatically.

Comment: Are you writing the modified class file? Are you loading via a javassist (or equivalent) class loader?

Comment: Aah.. That's right. That was the problem. I wasn't writing the updated class file.  
If you can move your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.
Thanks.